# How recognize between function call and class instantiation in IntelliJ or Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I learn Kotlin in Android, but many codes are scrap because I have problem recognize when is some code as call function or instantiate class.

Code not work, but for example is good:

```kotlin
    class Boo{
        val callFromFoo: Int = Foo(1)
        val instanceFoo: Foo = Foo(2)
    
        fun Foo(id: Int): Int {
            return id
        }
    }
    
    class Foo(val id: Int)
```

I'm concerned, because call Foo(1) and instantiating Foo(2) is the same code, without IDE recognizing of differences.
Note: explicit declaration is not standard in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the classes within the same file/package you could use reflection like so:

```kotlin
class Boo {
    val callFromFoo: Int = Foo(1)
    val instanceFoo: Foo = requireNotNull(Foo::class.primaryConstructor).call(2)

    fun Foo(id: Int): Int {
        return id
    }
}

class Foo(val id: Int)
```

If you have the classes in different packages, you could instantiate the object specifying that package. Like so:

```kotlin
class Boo {
    val callFromFoo: Int = Foo(1)
    val instanceFoo: Foo = com.android.example.package2.Foo(2)

    fun Foo(id: Int): Int {
        return id
    }
}
```

I would not recommend either of those solutions.

Note that classes are generally nouns like `Navigator`, `LoginUseCase`, `User`, `Logger` etc and functions are generally verbs or atleast use verbs like `navigateTo()`, `login()`, `processData()`, `log()` etc. I don`t think they should ever have the same name.

Furthermore, I think the coding style you are using does not go well with Kotlin. It will create unnecessary confusion between functions and classes even if they have different names. I suggest you follow the [official Kotlin coding style guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html). Have function names start with lower case and class names start with upper case to avoid any confusion.

**Update**

If you would like to stick to your coding convention and differentiate between constructor call and function call, you could choose varying colors for each in Android Studio or IntelliJ.

*Android Studio/IntelliJ*:
File > Settings > Editor > Color scheme > Kotlin

[image: Color scheme]

Result:
[image: Result color scheme]

Comment: Thanks Sharma, I'm C# programmer where is another coding style. Kotlin is not for me natural, that's why I'm looking another way for better acclimatization via IDE

Comment: @Abedron I have updated the answer to include a solution involving IDE. I am a C#  programmer as well. I have just been writing Kotlin for a few months. In my opinion, it is easier to get used to writing function names in lowercase than to get used to any IDE solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is much better;)